# 16 bit to 12 bit conversion between microcontroller and dac

Tags: embedded, microprocessors, mbed, 16-bit, dac

```
#include "mbed.h"
DigitalOut gpo(PTD7);
AnalogOut Aout(PTE30);
float x; 
unsigned int i,j;

int main() {
   x=0;
   i=0;
   while(1) {
      gpo=i & 1;
      x=16*2047.0*(1+sin(2*3.142*i/64));
      j=x; 
      Aout.write_u16(j);
      i++; 
   } 
}
```

This code is supposed to produce a sine wave from the DAC. The microcontroller I'm using is 16 bits while the DAC that the information is being sent to is 12 bits. The line x=... is the equation for a sine wave and produces new values for a sine wave every loop. Can someone explain why we need to multiply the value by 16*2047? like how does this help calibrate the waveform ?

Comment: Its possible the DAC is 12 bits, but is left justified in the 16 bit register.. (i.e. the bottom 4 bits are ignored).    This is "common" because fractional representation is very common in DSP (0xffff is ~1.0/full scale, 0x0000 is 0).   Your processing stays the same if you have a 16 bit dac, a 12 bit, or an 8 bit dac.

Comment: You need to read the manual to see how the DAC presents the data. Most often it can be configured. In case of external DAC then endianess is also a consideration.

Comment: It seems as if this is a homework question. Please [edit] your question and tell us what specifically you don't understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.